# Android: startActivity() starting a "chain" of activities?

Tags: android

Yes, I know. It sounds weird, but I can't think of any other way to explain it.

I start Activity MainActivity. It calls startActivity(B). B calls startActivity(C). In C, I have a button with an *onClickListener* that looks like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
```

When I hit the button, I get to activity B, not Main!

LogCat shows this:
Activitymanager   Starting activity: ... MainActivity
ActivityManager   Starting activity: ... B

So, it looks like my MainActivity (A) gets started and then something-or-someone-mysterious starts activity B immediately.

Ideas? I'm at a loss...

Thanks!
*Llappall*

EDIT:
A couple of notes to clarify:
1) I'm not overriding any lifecycle methods in MainActivity. I just have onCreate.
2) MainActivity's layout shows an image that covers the whole screen. I capture where the user touches in the image's OnTouchListener and, depending on that, I call different intents. The code looks like this:

```
if (touchX > 0 && touchX < 0.5 && touchY > 0.25
    && touchY < 0.46) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, ShowListsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("option", 0);
    startActivity(i);
} else if // if the location of the click is different I call another .class
```

Comment: Without the code for A's lifecycle methods, I can only speculate. Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: You may try to use startActivityForResult() instead. Not tried yet.

Comment: Presumably you mean `A` where you've written `MainActivity`?

Comment: Regarding the updated question, that sounds odd. I'm not quite managing to follow where all the activities are started. Is there a need for `A` to be the first activity (and for `B` to exist in that chain) if it's only ever accessed via `C`?

Comment: A is the MainActivity, which is the one the launcher starts. From it, the user can follow a "path" like this: A->B->C (all launched by user interactions). In ALL ACTIVITIES BUT A I have a "Start Over" button, that would take them to back to the MainActivity.   There are other paths the user can follow: A->D->E->F, for example.<br>So, what I need is a button that will take you "Home" in every activity.

Comment: The weird thing is that some paths work OK, as in A->D->E->(user clicks the "home" button)->A.  But in others, I get A->B->C->(user clicks the "home" button)->A->B (with the user not even seeing the A after the button).

Answer (score 1):

> In C, I have a button:
>   `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));`

You should use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

---

> I start Activity MainActivity. It calls startActivity(B).

Ok, so `MainActivity` (`A`) calls `B` as soon as it starts?
Therefore it seems completely reasonable that `B` starts when you call the `MainActivity` intent.

Presumably you're calling "start B" in the `onResume` method of `MainActivity` — that means, every time you return to `A` it will immediately start `B` again.

Instead, you should probably call "start B" only from `onCreate`.

Though as codelark says above, it would be helpful to detail the lifecycle methods you are employing.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for the explanation. As you can see in my edit of the question, my activity B _should_ start only when the user touches the screen. That is what's so perplexing about this: it is like the image's onTouchListener is being raised without the user's input.

Comment: Another question, if I may abuse of your help: you say I should use "this" instead of "getApplicationContext()". I've seen examples of both, but don't really understand what is the difference. What is that parameter used for? I understand one is the App context, the other is the current activity. What I don't get is why does that mater?